# New release on Google Play Store - Keystore was tampered with

Tags: android, google-play

I upload my application on Google Play Store using my keystore.jks. The application is on PlayStore everything is working fine.

So now its time to make another release to update my application. For that I'm using the same keystore.jks, but the problem is that AndroidStudio cannot build apk for me.

The problem is:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.
> Failed to read key release from store "C:\Users\keyStore.jks": Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
```

The password is correct! So I tried to recreate new keystore, but Google Play Store didn't let me to publish that apk, because the certificates are different.

So can I change my keystore or what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You must use the same key store.**

You cannot create a new key store and expect to use it to update the app.

"Keystore was tempered with, or password is incorrect" means your password is incorrect. Make sure you enter the alias and both passwords correctly.

Comment: There is a very less chance for the file to be corrupted. Try signing a different simple hello world app with that key. If the file is corrupted or you forgot your password, you cannot update the app.

Comment: You were right. I'm gonna kill my client... He gave me wrong password.....

Comment: I feel sorry for you and your client who is dying 